# Why does Android Studio show quick docs for string literals?

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc

Android Studio's quick doc pop-ups are buggy and occasionally unreliable, but one oddment in particular seems to occur all the time, which suggests it is a 'feature'. Behold:
[image]

Note the window title, 'Documentation for [string literal]' -- why would Android Studio consider a string literal to be a potentially javadoc documented code element?  Can I disable this behavior without affecting legitimate quick doc pop-ups (e.g. those for field and method names)? Worse, sometimes Android Studio will place the doc window somewhere above the cursor (not pictured) so it obscures my view of the relevant code.  Can the position of the quick docs window relative to the cursor be configured somewhere?

Comment: If you think this is the worst problem in Android Studio...I may have some bad news for you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question, the position of the documentation (quick docs) pop-up can be fixed:

1. When it is displaying, click the push-pin icon in the top-right of the pop-up to "Open as a Tool Window".
2. On this new tool window, click the gear-with-dropdown icon and uncheck "Floating Mode".

The window is then docked to the right side of the window by default but may be re-positioned or returned to a pop-up.